# Calling a function from another class - XNA 4.0 - C#

Tags: c#, class, function, xna

Basically I am trying to implement a save function into my game. When you click save in the menu, the game writes to a .txt file. From the MenuManager class I want to call a function within Game1.cs

This is the code in my MenuManager.cs

```
                case Menu.ButtonEvents.Save:
                    activeMenu.ButtonEvent = Menu.ButtonEvents.None;
                    game1.Save();
                    Show("Save Menu");
```

The third line is where I want to call the function in Game1.cs

In Game1.cs I have the save function

```
    public void Save()
    {
        // Example #1: Write an array of strings to a file. 
        // Create a string array that consists of three lines. 
        string[] lines = { levelIndex.ToString(), player.checkpointPos.X.ToString(), player.checkpointPos.Y.ToString() };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("WriteText.txt", lines);
    }
```

The problem for me is that I have all of the variables in Game1.cs, but the Save Button is pressed within the MenuManager system. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The menu manager needs access to the game object then. Is it a `GameComponent`?

Comment: Expose a property of the game object from within Game1 and then call `Game.Save()` etc.. from your manager class

Comment: What do you mean by 'Expose'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the `game1` variable to your `MenuManager` class.

Try something like this:

**MenuManager**

```
public Game1 Game
{
    get { return this._game; }
    set { this._game = value; }
}
private Game1 _game = null;
```

**Game1.cs**

```
this.MenuManager.Game = this;
```

In your function:

```
case Menu.ButtonEvents.Save:
activeMenu.ButtonEvent = Menu.ButtonEvents.None;
this.Game.Save();
Show("Save Menu");
```